# How to force nginx to stop redirecting a certain IP to a domain?

Tags: nginx, redirect

My Nginx is redirecting servers public IP to a domain even after I removed the vhost that was doing that and reloaded nginx?

I removed a vhost that had this set

```
server {
        listen ip.ip.ip.ip:80;
        server_name certain.domain.com;
    location ^~/ {
            ...
                return 301 https://certian.domain.com
```

Now every time I go to any browser and enter ip.ip.ip.ip it redirects to certain.domain.com even though I have nothing in my sites-enabled anymore that would do anything with that domain and I deleted the A record in my DNS.

Comment: And you've cleared those browser's cache?

Comment: Accessing your site by IP address doesn't use A records. If there is no matching `server_name`, Nginx will use the default server.

Comment: It redirect to domain from any browser, from any device anywhere. I know IP address don't have A records. I just can't figure out why my default server is redirecting to to a server name of my deleted vhost.